# Blogger displays 8 posts rather than 10 on the home page

Tags: blogger, homepage, blogspot

I have a blog on the blogger platform. On my homepage, there are 8 posts while I have it configured to show 10.  This is how I have it set up.

I tried putting "input jump" into the last post at different points, but it didn't change anything.  I also tried that in the 9th post, but nothing happens.

How can I get it display 10 posts instead of just 8?

Comment: To clarify, Blogger has a "show at most" this many posts on the home page which you changed to 10 as described in [this article](https://support.pipdig.co/articles/blogger-how-to-change-the-number-of-posts-displayed/).   However, Blogger limits the number of posts if there are too many images on the home page.  When you say "input jump", are you talking about putting the "read more" link into each post so that it doesn't show images on the home page as described in [this followup article](https://support.pipdig.co/articles/blogger-why-are-posts-missing-from-the-homepage/)?

Comment: Υes i have set it to "10" but it does not show it .. it only shows 8 posts .. not the "read more" .. look this video "40sec" and you will understand (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts2lxfdrZ5o)  ..I have done what she shows in the video but it did not work